# How to add config.ini file in Windows Services application?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, configuration-files

I have installed this application but problem is this application do not reading config.ini file i got error that config.ini does not exist? sure i am wrong i don't know how to add config.ini file in Setup Project?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.IO;

namespace MovimentoServic
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> vpN = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        cancelaments cancel = new cancelaments();
        vendas vendas = new vendas();
        Vendaecf ecf = new Vendaecf();
        Sangrias sangria = new Sangrias();
        Devolucao devolucao = new Devolucao();
        CancelamentECF cancelecf = new CancelamentECF();
        EnviarItemparalojas enivar = new EnviarItemparalojas();
        RecheckVendas recheck = new RecheckVendas();

        String vpn = null;
        String host = null;
        string user = null;
        string pass = null;
        string mysql_db = null;
        string vpn_db = null;
        String permissao = null;
        int count = 0;

        public void conect()
        {
            if ( System.IO.File.Exists("config.ini") )
            {
                String[] INI = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("config.ini");

                for ( int i = 0; i < INI.Length; i++ )
                {
                    if ( INI[i].StartsWith("HOST") )
                    {
                        host = INI[i].Substring(INI[i].IndexOf("=") + 1);
                    }
                    if ( INI[i].StartsWith("USER") )
                    {
                        user = INI[i].Substring(INI[i].IndexOf("=") + 1);
                    }
                    if ( INI[i].StartsWith("PASS") )
                    {
                        pass = INI[i].Substring(INI[i].IndexOf("=") + 1);
                    }
                    if ( INI[i].StartsWith("DBPATH") )
                    {
                        mysql_db = INI[i].Substring(INI[i].IndexOf("=") + 1);
                    }

                    if ( INI[i].StartsWith("VPN") )
                    {
                        vpn = (INI[i].Substring(INI[i].IndexOf("=") + 1));
                        Char[] cs = { ';' };
                        String[] VPN = vpn.Split(cs);
                        vpN.Add(VPN[0], VPN[1]);
                    }
                    if ( INI[i].StartsWith("DBPATH_VPN") )
                    {
                        vpn_db = (INI[i].Substring(INI[i].IndexOf("=") + 1));
                    }
                    if ( INI[i].StartsWith("Permissao") )
                    {
                        permissao = (INI[i].Substring(INI[i].IndexOf("=") + 1));
                    }

                }
            }

        }
        public static bool IsAlive( string aIP, String shop )
        {
            bool result = false;
            Ping pingSender = new Ping();
            PingOptions options = new PingOptions();
            options.DontFragment = true;
            string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            int timeout = 10;
            PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(aIP, timeout, buffer, options);
            if ( reply.Status == IPStatus.Success )
            {
                result = true;
            }
            return result;
        }


        long Validtime = 50;
        int tk = 0;
        private void timer1_Elapsed( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            tk++;
            if ( tk == Validtime )
            {
               // Workout();
                tk = 0;
            }

        }
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        protected override void OnStart( string[] args )
        {
            conect();

            Timer timer1 = new Timer();
            timer1.Interval = 100;
            timer1.Start();
            timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Elapsed);

        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the settings mechanisms built into the .NET Framework since version 2.0 instead of your `config.ini` file.

To do so, open the project's properties and go to the `Settings` tab. Add the settings you need (notice that an `app.config` file is being created, which is upon compilation copied to the output folder as `<projectname>.exe.config`). In your program, use the settings like

```
string myStringSetting = Properties.Settings.Default.MySetting
```

After installing the service, changing the `exe.config` file will make the service use the new settings after it is restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because you're making assumptions about the location of the ini file and how the service is launched.

In services you cannot depend on the current working directory to be in the same place every time. You should store the path to the configuration file in the registry (or even store the configuration data in the registry in the first place).